# What does the -y/-yacc flag do in bison?

Tags: bison

I searched the man page and found this. But... what does it mean? without it my bison file doesnt compile and i would like to know why it doesnt (admittedly i have a few shift/reduce and reduce/reduce errors. But that shouldnt stop it?).

Does anyone have a link to what it actually does or why it would not compile my code?

```
   -y, --yacc
          emulate POSIX Yacc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Bison generates one set of file names, but POSIX requires a different set of file names.  The `-y` flag makes Bison generate the POSIX names instead of its own set of names.

For input file name `grammar.y`, Bison normally produces `grammar.tab.c` (and `grammar.tab.h` if you request the header).  With the `-y` flag, Bison produces `y.tab.c` and `y.tab.h`.

Note that the `-y` flag should only affect the output file names.  It should have no effect on what is acceptable as a grammar, nor on the number of conflicts.

Interestingly, on the same grammar, the output is slightly different; the action lines have an empty statement in them:

```
$ diff y.tab.c grammar.tab.c
558c558
< #line 559 "y.tab.c"
---
> #line 559 "grammar.tab.c"
2828c2828
<     { stmt_type = STMT_NONE; }
---
>     { stmt_type = STMT_NONE; ;}
2833c2833
<     { stmt_type = STMT_LOAD; }
---
>     { stmt_type = STMT_LOAD; ;}
...
```